# Please help writing unix script for the below scenario

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

There is an `unload.dat` file with the list of `.ksh` file names. The task is to extract a few parameter details from each of the files that are present in the `unload.dat` file. Every file contains the below information.

Let us consider for first file name (`file_name1.ksh`) in the `unload.dat`:

```
graph_name = abcd.ksh

export name_a=value_a
export "name_b=value_b"
export name_c=value_c
export name_d=value_d
export name_e="value_e"
export name_f="value_f"
```

The next file's fetched data should be appended to the previous file's output in the same output file.

The output should look like the below:

```
abcd.ksh    name_a  value_a 1   filename_1.ksh
abcd.ksh    name_b  value_b 1   filename_1.ksh
abcd.ksh    name_c  value_c 1   filename_1.ksh
abcd.ksh    name_d  value_d 1   filename_1.ksh
abcd.ksh    name_e  value_e 1   filename_1.ksh


abcd.ksh    name_a  value_a 2   filename_2.ksh
abcd.ksh    name_b  value_b 2   filename_2.ksh
abcd.ksh    name_c  value_c 2   filename_2.ksh
abcd.ksh    name_d  value_d 2   filename_2.ksh
abcd.ksh    name_e  value_e 2   filename_2.ksh
```

Comment: Do we assume value_b translates to 1 or 2, etc, ?

Comment: Hi Jim value_b will be either of 0 or 1.In some .ksh script the value of this parameter is 0 and in some it is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

counter=1
while read -r filename; do
  if [ "$counter" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo
    echo
  fi

  IFS== read _ graph < "$filename"
  graph=${graph# }

  sed -n '/^export/{s/^[^ ]* //;s/"//g;p}' < "$filename" \
  | while IFS== read -r name value; do
    echo "$graph    $name  $value $counter   $filename"
  done

  counter=$((counter+1))
done < unload.dat
```

Comment: hi samsus thank you very much. I will verify and will get back in case of any questions.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=`cat unisc.txt | sed -n '1,1p' | cut -f3 -d' '`
var2=`cat unisc.txt | wc -l`
va1=1
var=`expr $var2 - 1`
echo $var
for ((i=1;i<=2;i++))
do
   for ((j=1;j<=$var;j++))
   do
      var3=`sed 's/"//g' unisc.txt | cut -f2 -d' ' | cut -f1 -d'=' | sed -n '2,'$var2'p' | sed -n $j'p'`
      var4=`sed 's/"//g' unisc.txt | cut -f2 -d' ' | cut -f2 -d'=' | sed -n '2,'$var2'p' | sed -n $j'p'`
      echo "$var1 $var3 $var4 $i filename_1.ksh"
    done
done
```